# Slow Read or Slow Write affects all drives

Tags: drivers, kernel, hard-drive, badblocks

I am running `Ubuntu 16.04` with `RocketRaid 2720SGL HBA board` that I have updated the firmware to take the RAID handler out and just use the ports.

There are two ports on the board that will allow a break out of four drives per port or a total of eight drives. I have two drives per port connected.

When the system comes up the board sees all four drives as 0, 1 for the first port and 4, 5 for the second port. This is fine.

When listing the drives I see them as sdb, sdc, sdd, and sde. In **/dev/disk/by-path** I see them as 0, 1, 4, 5. I use this to let me know which actual drive port is tied to which device id.

With four good 500 GB disks I can wipe all four drives in about 70 - 80 minutes which is the time it would take to wipe one drive. I use

```
if((RetVal = pthread_create(&DIptr->DI_ThreadFD, NULL, WipeTheDrive, DIptr)) != 0)
{
     printf("WIPESINGLEDRIVE: ERROR: return code from pthread_create() is %d errno: [%d]\n", RetVal, errno);
}
```

to execute the four threads independently. If  the drives do not have any bad sectors or any anomalies the wipe goes just fine. I open the drives using **O_RDWR|O_DIRECT** and I have my buffers set on the correct boundary so that I can use DMA using **WipeBuffer[1048576] __attribute__ ((__aligned__ (1048576)));**

This all works fine, I ran 240 drives through this logic at four drives at a time and never had a problem.

This is the situation however. If one of the four drives has bad sectors or has a slow write, or a slow read then it affects the timing of all the other drives. In other words, if drive 1 has bad sectors and sits waiting for the read or the write to return then the other drives also sit and wait. It acts as if they are sharing some type of queue or buffer and are all in line waiting their turn. I have routines that grade drives on read and write performance and I get a false failure if one drive has problems.

With all this being said, first of all I do not know what is causing this, is it the operating system queuing the tasks to the kernel, could it be the driver although I do not think this is it. I sent an email to the Marvell tech support people who are the developers of the firmware and they told me that each channel on the board is independent with one DMA channel for every four drives. I have split the drives between the two DMA channels and I still get a slow on all the drives if one is slow.

**What Should I change so I can get four independent channels without one affecting the other?**

=========================================================================

After the suggestion of using blktrace I installed it and ran it with four drives writing at the same time. The trace looked fine and seemed to be sharing the writes fairly well.

I then pulled one of the drives out and the trace looked like this

8,48   2      422     0.542202510 12017  Q  WS 581826560 + 2048 [client]

8,48   2      423     0.542207566 12017  Q  WS 581827584 + 1024 [client]

8,48   2      424     0.542208902 12017  G  WS 581826560 + 1024 [client]

8,48   2      425     0.542213507 12017  G  WS 581827584 + 1024 [client]

8,48   2      426     0.542214337 12017  I  WS 581826560 + 1024 [client]

8,48   2      427     0.542214854 12017  I  WS 581827584 + 1024 [client]

8,48   2      428     0.542221516   289  D  WS 581826560 + 1024 [kworker/2:1H]

8,48   2      429     0.542228504   289  R  WS 581826560 + 1024 [0]

8,48   2      430     0.542228808   289  I  WS 581826560 + 1024 [kworker/2:1H]

8,48   2      431     0.542572302   289  D  WS 581826560 + 1024 [kworker/2:1H]

8,48   2      432     0.542572979   289  R  WS 581826560 + 1024 [0]

8,48   2      433     0.542573279   289  I  WS 581826560 + 1024 [kworker/2:1H]

8,48   2      434     0.546583088   289  D  WS 581826560 + 1024 [kworker/2:1H]

8,48   2      435     0.546583892   289  R  WS 581826560 + 1024 [0]

8,48   2      436     0.546584227   289  I  WS 581826560 + 1024 [kworker/2:1H]

8,48   2      437     0.550587702   289  D  WS 581826560 + 1024 [kworker/2:1H]

8,48   2      438     0.550588397   289  R  WS 581826560 + 1024 [0]

8,48   2      439     0.550588711   289  I  WS 581826560 + 1024 [kworker/2:1H]

8,48   2      440     0.554580452   289  D  WS 581826560 + 1024 [kworker/2:1H]

8,48   2      441     0.554581354   289  R  WS 581826560 + 1024 [0]

8,48   2      442     0.554581664   289  I  WS 581826560 + 1024 [kworker/2:1H]

You can see where 'client' which is the name of the executable is queuing up the writes, and then the 'kworker' process just stays and hammers away at the drive that I pulled. This is only a small sample but it runs for pages and pages and the client never gets a chance to issue any new writes for the other three drives at all. It is my understanding that a 'kworker' process is a kernel process that is working with the I/O of the devices.

**So my question now is, how can I get the 'kworker' process to not monopolize the entire I/O process and share the channels with the rest of the devices when a drive either goes offline or has a slow write or read.**

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the driver isn't issuing more than one request at a time.  You might take a look at the `blktrace` tool to analyze what is going on in the IO stack.  If the driver is working correctly, you should see multiple requests in the D(ispatch) state at the same time.  If there is only one, then that's the problem.

Comment: Thank you, I will do that and let you know what the outcome was